Problems opening external workbook
I want to have a workbook import a string from a table in another workbook, but have a strange issue where opening the second workbook causes most of my code to be skipped over.
I'm running this from Workbook_Open. I'm basically trying to open the file, read the data from the table, assign the data to some labels on a userform then show the form.
Here is my current code:
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        
    Call Globals

    'OrderNum = InputBox("Enter order number:", "Order Number")
    PartNum = "20240471102"
    'PartNum = System.PrivateProfileString("\\FILENORTH01\Database\Production\HCSSerialNoLog\Orders.ini", OrderNum, "PartNumber")
    'FirstSerial = System.PrivateProfileString("\\FILENORTH01\Database\Production\HCSSerialNoLog\Orders.ini", OrderNum, "FirstSerial")
    'LastSerial = System.PrivateProfileString("\\FILENORTH01\Database\Production\HCSSerialNoLog\Orders.ini", OrderNum, "LastSerial")
    'LeadQty = System.PrivateProfileString("\\FILENORTH01\BLAKELL\VAB\Weetech Reports\ini Files\Variations.ini", "FibreLeads", PartNum)
    
    Set dwb = Workbooks.Open("J:\ProdEng\TIS Masters\TIS MASTER TEMPLATES\Data Sheets\TISData.xlsx")
    Set FibreSheet = dwb.Sheets("FibreData")
    
    Set tbl = FibreSheet.ListObjects("FibreOps")
    Set dataRange = tbl.DataBodyRange
    TestOps = dataRange.Value
    
    Set tbl = FibreSheet.ListObjects("FibrePartData")
    Set PartCol = tbl.ListColumns("Part number:")
    Set foundCell = PartCol.DataBodyRange.Find(PartNum)
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        rowNumber = foundCell.Row
        LeadA = tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(rowNumber, tbl.ListColumns("Test Lead End A:").Index).Value
        Debug.Print "Lead A: " & LeadA
        LeadB = tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(rowNumber, tbl.ListColumns("Test Lead End B:").Index).Value
        Debug.Print "Lead B: " & LeadB
        TestDataForm.LeadResultA.Caption = LeadA
        TestDataForm.LeadResultB.Caption = LeadB
    End If
    
    dwb.Close False
    
    TestDataForm.OpsBox.List = TestOps
    TestDataForm.Show
    
End Sub

I'm declaring everything globally in a "Globals" module before any of this runs:
Public OrderNum As Long, PartNum As String, FirstSerial As Long, LastSerial As Long, LeadQty As Integer, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, dwb As Workbook, FibreSheet As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, dataRange As Range, TestOps() As Variant, ComboBox As ComboBox, LeadA As Variant, LeadB As Variant, PartCol As ListColumn, foundCell As Range, rowNumber As Long, TestDataForm As Object

Public Sub Globals()
End Sub

If the source workbook is open before the code runs everything seems to work. However, if the source workbook starts out as closed (which it generally will under normal use), the file is opened but all code up to "TestDataFrom.Show" is totally ignored.

So if you step through your code with F8 all lines between Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(...) and TestDataForm.Show are ignored?

I was actually mistaken about what was happening here. When debug stepping through the code it seemed to be skipping over, but was actually just flying through it for some reason. It turns out the form wasn't showing due to an error in its UserForm_Initialize code.

So this is resolved?
